# How can I provide conditions in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update the database table. How can I prevent the password ("MemberPassword", $ pass) coming from the form from being updated with sql codes by providing a condition if it is empty? Is it possible?

```
   //database connection
        $SQL = "mysql:host=" . $this->MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . $this->MYSQL_DB;

        try {
            $this->pdo = new \PDO($SQL, $this->MYSQL_USER, $this->MYSQL_PASS);
            $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES'" . $this->CHARSET . "'COLLATE'" . $this->COLLATION . "'");
            $this->pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET'" . $this->CHARSET . "'");
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die( $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    //Connect DB END

    private function myQuery($query, $params = null)
        {
            if (is_null($params)) {
                $this->stmt = $this->pdo->query($query);
            } else {
                $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
                $this->stmt->execute($params);
            }
            return $this->stmt;
        }
    
    
        public function Update($query, $params = null)
            {
                try {
                    return $this->myQuery($query, $params)->rowCount();
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
    
    
            
            $update = $db->Update("UPDATE members SET
            MemberUsername=?,
            MemberPassword=?,
            MemberEmail=?,
            MemberName=?,
            MemberLastName=?,
            MemberBirthday=?,
            MemberAge=?,
            MemberGender=?,
            CityID=?
            WHERE MemberID=?
            ", array($username, $pass, $email, $name, $lastname, $birthday, $age, $gender, $city, $memberID));
```

Comment: is `Update()` method taken from some API? MySQLi or PDO, doesn't have such a method. Add more details about what you're trying to do, or it will be closed.

Comment: `MemberPassword=CASE WHEN ? = '' THEN MemberPassword ELSE ? END,` - and the password value must be transferred twice.

Comment: Or write PHP logic to vary the content of the SQL (i.e. don't put the MemberPassword bit into the SQL string or the parameters) if the submitted password is blank. Simple.

Comment: Or, some applications make changing password a completely separate piece of functionality, with separate UI and separate endpoint, different to updating general profile data. Consider the user experience aspect of this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy use **IFNULL(expr1,expr2)** like:

IFNULL returns expr1 if they is not null else expr2

```
$update = $db->Update("UPDATE members SET
            MemberUsername=?,
            MemberPassword=IFNULL(?,MemberPassword),
            MemberEmail=?,
            MemberName=?,
            MemberLastName=?,
            MemberBirthday=?,
            MemberAge=?,
            MemberGender=?,
            CityID=?
            WHERE MemberID=?
            ", array($username, $pass, $email, $name, $lastname, $birthday, $age, $gender, $city, $memberID));
```

Comment: @BerndBuffen I'm so sorry. I was a mistake and I cannot remove it. I tried sometimes to do upvote but StackOverflow says your vote is locked in unless this answer is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this in your php code:

```
 $param = array($username, $email, $name, $lastname, $birthday, $age, $gender, $city);

 $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE members SET  
    MemberUsername=?,
    MemberEmail=?,
    MemberName=?,
    MemberLastName=?,
    MemberBirthday=?,
    MemberAge=?,
    MemberGender=?,
    CityID=?"
   

 if(!is_null(pass)) {
    $sqlUpdate = $sqlUpdate . ", MemberPassword = ?";
    array_push($param , $pass);
 }

 $sqlUpdate = $sqlUpdate . " WHERE MemberID=?";
 array_push($param , $memberID);

 $update = $db->Update($sqlUpdate, $param);
```

You can use this pattern for all other fields.

Comment: you forgot to also vary the parameter list by the same criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, that wasn't exactly the solution i was looking for. $pass can come from the form as an empty string (""). And it can be update as an empty string in database . Maybe we need !is_empty() but still more complex than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what your question exactly is but I think this is what you want :
User submits a form and if Password that sent from this form was not empty then update everything including password, otherwise update everything except password!
For do this you can use if statement in your SQL Query

```
$update = $db->Update("UPDATE members SET
MemberUsername=?,
MemberPassword=IF(? IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(?) > 0, ?, MembersPassword),
MemberEmail=?,
MemberName=?,
MemberLastName=?,
MemberBirthday=?,
MemberAge=?,
MemberGender=?,
CityID=?
WHERE MemberID=?
", array($username, $pass, $pass, $pass, $email, $name, $lastname, $birthday, $age, $gender, $city, $memberID));
```

Comment: Exactly it is.it was very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Also you can use Coalesce(?, MembersPassword), this returns first non-null value in the inputs (in here ? and MembersPassword are my inputs and it can be more than 2) but I wrote with IF and two conditions for that condition if password is not null but was an empty string (null and empty string are diffrent) it works too.

Comment: you are right. i have to before Coalesce
if(strlen($pass)=0){
$pass=null;
}

Comment: You can use just IF(? IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(?) > 0, ?, MembersPassword), it works so good for you, just edit array and put two more $pass in it